# Is this solution enough to block SQL Injections

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I made my simple PHP search script, but I'm not sure if this solution is enough to avoid sql injections.

The only input I have there is search query input. The thing is, when someone submits my form, javascript have to push `%` character to the beginning and to the end of query string and also have to replace all spaces and special characters with `%`. After that using GET method I send it on my server.

Using PDO(`execute([$query])`, not bindParam), and using if statement like this one bellow, where I check first character and whitespaces, is it enough to block sql injections?

```
if($_GET['query'][0]!='%' || preg_match('/\s/',$_GET['query'])) {
   die();}
```

I mean, I can't imagine SQL query without spaces and with '%' at the index of zero.

Comment: Is there something about using parameters that is particularly difficult?

Comment: @GordonLinoff which parameters

Comment: Depends on the rest of your code, adding a % to the beginning and the end and replacing spaced with % doesn't change anything to sql injection risk.

Comment: No, this is not enough to block SQL injection. Any solution you come up with, especially if it involves regular expressions, will fail. Use prepared queries and parameter binding. That is the only proper solution.

Comment: @BertBijn so you say "select * from users" is the same thing like "%select*fromusers". i dont think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using PDO(execute([$query]), not bindParam)

It is not `bindParam`/`bindValue` that makes your query safe but `:parameter`  that is used in the query. As long as you have all variables in your query substituted with parameters, your query is 100% safe.

So you can tell that using execute() is enough and you don't need anything else to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you know what you are doing exactly, and you have experience in security and pentesting, NEVER try to do it yourself. Do not try to secure against sql injection by escaping or regex.

Chars can be escaped in ways you can't imagine when you have no experience. Security libraries are going to be mantained and updated faster than your code.

See this attacks as examples to break your code https://websec.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/exploiting-hard-filtered-sql-injections/